# How to correctly save a WF4 ActivityBuilder

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am currently saving my .NET FX 4.0.1 StateMachine activity like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var xamlWriter = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter(
                     new XamlXmlWriter(new StringWriter(sb),
                     new XamlSchemaContext()));
XamlServices.Save(xamlWriter, activityBuilder);

return sb.ToString();
```

This works fine and the generated XAML looks good. Unfortunately, it is invalid. I can read it back in using `ActivityXamlServices.Load` but when I execute it, it says that it doesn't know the properties defined in the workflow. Opening it in the Visual Studio designer yields the same errors:

> Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "ActiveCall". "ActiveCall" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Through comparing the original XAML with the XAML produced by my code, I found out how to fix this problem. I have to have this tag before the `StateMachine` tag:

```
<mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
    Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation
</mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
```

By the way:
The text inside the tag must be exactly like this, otherwise there will be an error when opening the WF in VS:

> Failed to create a 'Settings' from the text 'FooBar'

**Question:**
What do I have to change in my code to have this tag in the generated XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

I have to use the following code before calling `Save`:

```
VisualBasic.SetSettings(activityBuilder, new VisualBasicSettings());
```

---

If the `activityBuilder` has been created from a `DynamicActivity` it is even better to use the following code:

```
VisualBasic.SetSettings(activityBuilder,
                        VisualBasic.GetSettings(dynamicActivity));
```

If this is not used, namespaces that are only needed for extension methods are not written to the XAML and will lead to an error when loading and executing the XAML.

---

I summarized my findings on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429462/Saving-and-loading-Workflow-Foundation-4-activitie).

Comment: The most magical of magic strings.  Yes, you are correct.  It is an attached DependencyProperty.

Comment: I only found this out by browsing the .NET FX reference source and searching for this string... Strange that I haven't found this info anywhere on the net when people talked about saving an activity to XAML...

Comment: @Will: And I just found out, that you fought this issue, too: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/715057/wf-activity-validation-does-not-respect-object-oriented-principals-in-certain-situations :-)

Comment: :) yeap.  Tho I was able to figure out the solution relatively quickly (six days max, probably one day total) because of my experience with attached properties in WPF.  Check my workaround (posted four months before a MS rep replies to tell me I'm stpuid.  Harumph.)  **"Look at that magic string. Look at it. It is the most magic of magic strings I've ever seen in just about any framework I've ever used. In fact, it will now be my official magic phrase that I utter before doing something extraordinary.**"

Comment: @Will: Yeah, saw that. Once I knew it was that tag it took me only a few hours... But finding out that this ... *sentence* ... has such a severe impact took me a while. It was literally the **very last** difference in my XAML files I eliminated, and I couldn't believe it. The answer by MS is just arrogant - it is not documented in any way that something like this is necessary.

Comment: It works whithout that nasty string in .NET 4.5, perhaps because of Will´s entry on connect ;) I will update my framework to support State Machines, BTW thanks for the bounty Daniel

Comment: @selen: You are welcome. Please have a look at my updated answer, it might be relevant for your Framework.